# Qt: VectorIterator qt is not type

Tags: c++, qt, qvector

I need to create a QVectorIterator to iterate a QVector of QStrings as follows:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QVectorIterator>

#include <QLabel>
#include <QTimer>

class Dice : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

    private:
        QVector<QString> dice_faces;
        QVectorIterator<QString> it( dice_faces );
        QTimer *timer;
    ...
```

But I get this error, and don't understand what is wrong, or did QVectorIterator can't iterate over QString vector?

```
Dice.h:16: error: 'dice_faces' is not a type
     QVectorIterator<QString> i( dice_faces );
                                 ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the iterator in the initializer list in the constructor

```
#include <QString>
#include <QVectorIterator>

#include <QLabel>
#include <QTimer>

class Dice : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Dice(QObject *parent);

    private:
        QVector<QString> dice_faces;
        QVectorIterator<QString> it( dice_faces );
        QTimer *timer;
    // ...
```

dice.cpp

```
// ...

Dice::Dice(QObject *parent)
  : QLabel(parent),
    it(dice_faces)
{
}
```

Comment: I Knew it will be a stupid question, I'm under pression..., thanks anyway

Comment: You're welcome. I still don't think this is a beautiful solution. Consider declaring the iterator in the local scope where you iterate only.